# Hide/reveal navigation responding according to the user scrolling (no animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, transition

I'm creating a header where parts will be hidden when the user scrolls down and revealed  again on scroll up. Similar to the way http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/ navigation works. This I have setup and it's working properly.

**> Now I want to tweak the reveal/hide event to be contextually aware, i.e. respond according to the users scroll speed and not with a predermined animation.**

A lot of mobile apps have this behaviour. In lack of any other good example please have a look at Google's (after performing a search) or Facebook's iOS apps where the navigation is being revealed when the user starts to scroll back up.

I'm not sure where to start with this so anyone pointing me in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: This is a perfect example of what I'm looking for: https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/a-mathematical-proof-that-the-universe-could-have-formed-spontaneously-from-nothing-ed7ed0f304a3